# SSIS: the way of mapping of excel destination editor even though the mapping title is null

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm using SSIS. I'd try to set the sql data at excel. I made a few field name at the excel, and some of them succeed for mapping.

However, I need to find out the way even though the field is null

For example if the excel A1 cell is null, but B1,C1,D1 set the field name.
the mapping of excel destination editor show the B,C,D field name for mapping.

but I'd like to map the A1(null) to one of the sql field.
do you know any idea even the excel field name is null but can connect one of the sql field.

Addition, I have already done script task. Unfortunately, client enviroment doesn't have system for using excel, but I comfirm to be able to use excel destination editor. I need to find out how to map the data even though the field is null.

Please show me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

When you defining your Excel Conneciton, please uncheck the "First row has column names" box.

[image]

ALL columns will now be available with generic names: F1, F2, F3, F4...

[image]

Column F1 will start in cell A1.  You can rename those columns to whatever you like using the Advanced editor.  Right-click the Excel file source, click show Advanced Editor and rename them as desired.

More over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513867/how-to-use-the-column-names-specified-in-excel-files-first-row-within-a-package).

Comment: Good deal.  Glad I could help.